# How many iterations are needed when a new constraint is added

Tags: optimization, operations-research

Define a non negative linear programming problem as

Max $c^T x$

s.t

$Ax \leq b$

$x \geq 0$

where $a_{ij}\geq 0, \, b_i \geq 0, \, c\geq 0$ with m rows and n columns of $A$

If at optimality, a single new constraint is added which is not satisfied by the previous solution, what is the upper bound on the number of dual simplex iterations required to reach a new optimal solution?

Comment: Your thoughts on this question?